Mysql Drop stored procedure on update
Some time ago i create a simple stored procedure:
CREATE DEFINER=`someuser`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_foundRows`()
    READS SQL DATA
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
    SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS count;
END

it work fine. But when i trying to update it Mysql Workbench give`s me that code:
USE `mydb`;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `sp_foundRows`;

USE `mydb`;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `mydb`.`sp_foundRows`;
;

DELIMITER $$
USE `mydb`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`someuser`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_foundRows`()
    READS SQL DATA
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
    SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS count;
END
-- Just a comment to procedure$$

DELIMITER ;
;

and an error message:
Error getting DDL for object PROCEDURE sp_foundRows does not exist.

After that sp_foundRows just disappearing from db. I can recreate it, but i can`t update created one. What can be problem?
Edit: I found that the problem occurs if the comment is in the last line. If I don't change the last line, but make changes to any other lines, then everything is saved perfectly.

What can be problem? Workbench

PS. Does this is one solid code line really: -- Just a comment to procedure$$?

There are a couple of standalone semi-colons , why? and the end clause should be terminated by the delimiter $$

@Akina,  The problem is not the comments - it's just an example. The problem is that the procedure is dropped if I make any changes to the procedure.

The problem is that the procedure is dropped if I make any changes to the procedure. This is NOT a problem, this is an algorithm of the SP code change. There is no way to edit existing SP code, only drop and recreate is available.

@Akina You're right.. Drop is working out, but a new function is not being created and I'm starting to think that you were initially right and this is a Workbench problem - thank you for your time.

Provided error message is NOT MySQL error message. It is generated by Workbench, it seems.
